# Having a minor error with MySQL&Nodejs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, sockets

I'm having a minor error, while parsing trade tokens from a MYSQL database

> `/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77
>           throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>                 ^ TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at Query._callback (/bot/bot_source.js:974:32)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
>       at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:144:8)
>       at Query.EofPacket (/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:128:8)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
>       at Parser.write (/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
>       at Protocol.write (/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
>       at Socket.<anonymous> (/bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)`

the code :

```
if (body.response.trade_offers_received) {


            body.response.trade_offers_received.forEach(function(offer) {
                if (offer.trade_offer_state == 2) {
                    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `steamid`="'+offer.steamid_other+'"',function(usrerr,usrres,usrfields){
                    if(usrres.length==0){
                        console.log('user does not exist in database: '+offer.steamid_other);
                        return;
                    }
                    var tlink=usrres[0].tlink;
                    if (tlink == '') {
                        console.log('no trade link in db for user: '+offer.steamid_other);
                        return;
                    }
                    var tokenStr = tlink.split('token=', 2);
                    var token = tokenStr[1];

                    offers.getHoldDuration({
                        partnerSteamId:offer.steamid_other,
                        accessToken:token,
                    }, function (holderr,duration) {
                        if(holderr){
                                console.log('holdduration error: '+holderr);
                                return;
                            }
                        if ((duration.my != 0) || (duration.their != 0)) {
                        myconsolelog('Trade declined because either the bot or the person sending the offer has a trade period '+offer.tradeofferid);
                        offers.declineOffer({
                            tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid
                        });
                        declinedoffer=true;
                        if(duration.their!=0){
                            var unixtime = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000.0);
                            var messagedata={to:offer.steamid_other,msg:'Trade declined. You can not instantly trade because you are not using trade confirmations through the mobile authenticator.',time:unixtime,type:'tradehold'};
                            io.emit('message',messagedata);
                        }
                        return;
                    } }); });
```

`

I would like it to retrieve the trade token, after "token=", but it seems to catch an error on the way,

I would love any suggestion.

Comment: It seems that your query is getting "injected" some `steamid_other` may contain a single quote `'` on it that would break your code. Though I'm note sure if this is your real problem.

Comment: it says that in the file /bot/bot_source.js on line 974 you are attempting to call and undefined variable as a function. whats on line 974 in bot_source.js

Comment: offers.getHoldDuration({  is the start of 974 :)

Comment: where is offers defined.  i see offer as an argument to the function. but not "offers".  In any case its saying that offers.getHoldDuration() is undefined. could be either your object name or method name is incorrect.  or maybe the offers object is not in scope

Comment: Alright thanks Korrey. :)